# jquery filter on table works first time but after that hides all rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-filter

I've created a filter to show only rows containing `td`'s with the value selected from a dropdown. The filter works fine first time but second time i run it, all rows dissapear and I cant figure out why.
This is my filter:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name=selectedName]').change(function() {
        $('tr').filter(function () {
            return $(this).find('td.userName').filter(function () {
                return $(this).text().indexOf($('select[name=selectedName]').val()) == -1;
            }).length;
        }).hide();
    });
});
```

The drop down:

```
$query = "SELECT user_name FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query); ?>
<select name="selectedName" id="userSelected">
    <option value="" disabled selected>user name</option>
    <?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $line['user_name'];?>">
            <?php echo $line['user_name'];?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

And finally the creation of the table:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" ng-controller="tableCtrl">
        <thead>
        <th>user name</th>
        <th>script name</th>
        <th>cron format<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></th>
        <th>schedule last update</th>
        <th>next execution time</th>
        <th>script exec</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="(user_id,script_id) in data">
            <tr ng-repeat="(script_id, cron_format) in script_id">
                <td class="userName">{{user(user_id)}}</td>
                <td class="scriptName">{{script(script_id)}}</td>
                <td class="cronFormat"><span contenteditable="true" ng-repeat="l in letters(cron_format) track by $index">{{l}}</span></td>
                <td>{{compare(user_id,script_id,cron_format)[0]}}</td> <!--[0] represents scheduler last update-->
                <td>{{compare(user_id,script_id,cron_format)[1]}}</td> <!--[1] represents next execution time-->
                <td>{{compare(user_id,script_id,cron_format)[2]}}</td> <!--[2] represents script_exec-->
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Any idea why is it happening? Thanks for helping...

**UPDATE**

i added `$('tr').show();` and function works except, how can i add value in dropdown to show the all table/cancel the filter?

Answer (score 2):

You take care of hiding rows, but you never show them back. This is why your table sooner or later will have all rows invisible.

Comment: Call `.show()` method before your `.filter()` call.